# SQL Query basis on given limitation in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Parent  Table:

```
Cate_Name | Warn_Qty
--------------------
CAT1      | 40
Test      | 10
Test1     |  5
Test1     | 10
```

Transaction table

```
CAT1    |   25
Test    |   5
Test2   |   50
Test1   |   50
```

Here I'm looking for one query.

In the Parent Table, the `Cate_Name` and `Warn_Qty` values will be user defined.
Cate_Name would be n.. no. and below it is transaction table

The query should output only the records from the `Transaction table` that have less or equal quantity than the corresponding `Parent table`'s `Warm_Qty`

Output example here table will look like

```
    Parent  Table
    CAT1    |   40
    Test    |   10

    Transaction table
    CAT1    |   25
    Test    |   5
```

Note : - In the query, the `Cate_Name` would be multiple not fix category only

Comment: here I tried using subquery but not getting proper output as categ every time getting changed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.category_name, t.warn_qty 
 FROM 
    parent_table p, transaction_table t 
 WHERE 
    p.category_name = t.category_name   -- the join
    t.warn_qty <= p.warn_qty            -- the qualifier
```

Unless I'm missing something here.      It's essentially saying "gimme everything from transaction table where the warn_qty is less than the matching warn_qty in parent table, joined by category name."

It should be noted that with SQL2008 and greater, it's recommended you write out your JOINs fully, instead of shortcutting like I did above.    I'm old-school though, and still think this is more readable for simple joins.

Comment: Implicit joins has been out of style since about 1992. Maybe it's time to start using proper explicit ANSI standard SQL joins. For some reasoning on why you might want to stop using pre 92 syntax see [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I can appreciate your subjective opinion (even if your 1992 commentary is absurd). T-SQL has deprecated implicit *outer* joins (since SQL2005), but inners are still acceptable.   FWIW, the code pattern is up to the developer.  What works for me or you isn't going to always be the same.  Performance wise, in MSSQL - there is no difference.   I'll grant you that explicits are easier to read if you have to join a lot of tables - but if you're joining over three tables - do it differently.

Comment: Your query is worked but one thing.Here im facing different problem in child I don't have values in int values are like Cate1 25 then in qty section CAT1 25 times appear.So here I tried using count function but getting aggregation function error

Comment: @user3172930 -- I'm not sure I understand.  Are you looking to group these?   If you put an aggregate function in your SELECT, you need to include a GROUP BY so it know to aggregate on it. If the quantity field is an `NVARCHAR` field, you'll need to do some string manipulation to parse it and get the actual INT value you want -- but that's another question to be asked.

Comment: @Jason Yes, it's my subjective view, but I would consider adhering to the standard a best practice. Maybe I shouldn't have said _out of style_ though but rather _not standard since SQL:1992_ since that was what I meant.

Comment: Which means you're going to want to start looking at T-SQL `SUBSTRING` (and probably `RIGHT`) - to get whatever's right side of your string and put that into a variable.

Comment: Hi I know it should ask in different questino but it seems similar. Here just consider in trans table instead int Test appears 5 Times in string then basis on master table how can wo do same operation

Answer (score 1):

try an inner join with multiple conditions.

```
select trans.category, trans.qty
from transactiontable trans
inner join parenttable parent on 
trans.Category = parent.Category
and trans.qty <= parent.warn_Qty
```